# Send error message on redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I have a login form `/login` that posts the login info to `/checklogin`. If the credentials are incorrect, I want to redirect the user to `/login` with an error message along the lines of "incorrect username or password". However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass an option through `res.redirect` like you would using `res.render`.

What's the best way of doing this? I saw a prior question asked about this, but it doesn't seem to work in the later versions of Express.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With a redirect alone, it's not really possible to pass options other than in the query-string:

```
res.redirect('/login?e=' + encodeURIComponent('Incorrect username or password'));
```

A redirect instructs the client to start a new request and HTTP is on its own stateless.

To keep the message otherwise, you'll need a form of persistence to hold it for that next request -- cookies, sessions, etc.

```
req.session.error = 'Incorrect username or password';
res.redirect('/login');
```

Then:

```
res.render('login', { error: req.session.error });
delete res.session.error; // remove from further requests
```

This is also what Express 2's [`req.flash()`](http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html#req.flash%28%29) helped accomplish. And, a variant of it is still available for use with Express 3 and later -- just as [`connect-flash`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) rather than [being bundled](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x).

Comment: In the situation where you can't use res.render? like in the case of `react-native` app

Answer (score 3):

Server side:

```
res.redirect('/login?error=' + encodeURIComponent('Incorrect_Credential'));
```

In view there will be a alert (Hope you guys are using bootstrap). But initially it will be hide. If error comes, it will be shown.

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="loginAlert">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Incorrect Credential</p>
</div>
```

Showing Technique:

```
<script>
    $('#loginAlert').hide();
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const myParam = urlParams.get('error');
    if(myParam == "Incorrect_Credential") {
        $('#loginAlert').show();
    }
</script>
```